# Where can I find more detailed documentation on what chart settings can be used in Google-cloud-datalab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I am using the %chart magic in DataLab to generate charts. I see in the samples that there are options that can be specified in the cell body to fine-tune these charts. Where do I find documentation on these?

Answer (score 2):

The charts generated with %chart are using Google's chart tools (https://developers.google.com/chart/). The documentation there describes the options available for each chart. For example, the options for bubble charts are documented at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart#configuration-options.

In DataLab, you can specify these options in the cell using either JSON or YAML.

You can get limited help by using %chart --help and %chart <charttype> --help. The help shown there should get much better in a future release.

Comment: See https://github.com/fhoffa/notebooks/blob/master/analyzing%20hacker%20news.ipynb for an example

Comment: Graham - please can you give a pointer on the precise syntax to use for adding options via json or yaml? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone remains confused about this an example of the syntax is as follows:

```
%%chart scatter --data births
title: Birth Weight vs Weeks
height: 400
width: 900
hAxis:
  title: Weeks
vAxis:
  title: Weight
legend: none
```