# Better documentation for charts

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Can you point me to better documentation for charts.

I can do the following but this does not show me the different options for the charts. For instance what would I have to set for the line colors to be red.

usage: %%chart line [-h] [-f FIELDS] -d DATA

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FIELDS, --fields FIELDS
                        The field(s) to include in the chart
  -d DATA, --data DATA  The name of the variable referencing the Table or
                        Query to chart

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155993/where-can-i-find-more-detailed-documentation-on-what-chart-settings-can-be-used

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the Data Format table on [the respective Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) to understand what the parameters should be.

Comment: I'd like to add that I was somewhat skeptical of this approach at first, but thus far seems to follow the specs properly.

Comment: I and I suspect others could do with a pointer as to the precise syntax used to add these options. It's a really good chart library, but customisation is sorely needed for using it in datalab. Would you be able to expand this answer? I, and I'm sure others too, would greatly appreciate it.